# Javascript/Jquery being used n BPM issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

Basically, I can easily use this code to turn the individual dropdown into a chosen dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dropdown = $('#ContactName').getControl().chosen();
});
```

How would I use this to turn all of the dropdowns into chosen dropdowns without copy and pasting each line with the individual ID? I'm pretty new to Jquery/Javascript but first thing comes to mind is a class, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this because I can't edit the html for each dropdown individually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dropdown = $(".givenclass").getControl().chosen();
});
```

Comment: A class would without doubt be the best way. If, for whatever, reason you cannot add classes, then you can combine the id selectors in a single object, eg `$('#ContactName, #foo, #bar').chosen()`

Comment: Is there any way that I would be able to make the selector grab all of the dropdowns? Under the web controls I see property as "type" and the vale as "dropdown". If that helps.

Comment: That's not a standard HTML attribute, but assuming that renders out to a `select` control, you could simply use `$('select').chosen()` instead

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. Here is an image of what it looks like - http://i.imgur.com/lfUSCzF.png

Comment: Don't use `*` aside from the fact that means you're trying to instantiate that plugin on *every* element in the DOM, it's really slow. Did you try `$('select')`?

Comment: Yes I did try select as well. It does not load when using that.